# Map not visible with geoJSF

Tags: java, jsf, jboss7.x

I'm trying the example from [geoJSF](http://www.geojsf.org/geojsf/showcase/layer), but the page is alays empty and no map is shown. I don't get any error messages using version 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT from the Sonatype Snapshot Repository like described in the tutorial and JBoss AS 7.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:geojsf="http://geojsf.sourceforge.net/ui">
 <f:view contentType="text/html">
  <h:head>
   <title>Test</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
   <geojsf:map id="map">
    <geojsf:layer url="http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0" name="OSM" layers="basic"/>
   </geojsf:map>
  </h:body>
 </f:view>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show your whole JSF page. Also, there could be a problem in your configuration that you haven't shown us

Comment: I've added the whole page. If I add other element, e.g. of primefaces, there are no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm developer of geojsf and currently we are preparing the initial 0.1.0 release. During this process the namespace has changed to

```
xmlns:geojsf="http://geojsf.org/ui"
```

I've also updated the tutorial, sorry for the trouble!